# Fermi's Law of Beta Decay - the matrix element?

Tags: radiation, scattering

In Fermi's law of beta decay we have the matrix element:
\[ \int \psi_p^* \psi_{e}^* \psi_\nu^*H'\psi_ndr^3\]
on which several assumptions are made, firstly we assume that $\psi_{e}$ and $\psi_\nu$ can be treated as plane waves since this holds away from the potential. i.e.
$$\psi_{e}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{i\vec k\vec r}\tag{1}$$
and likewise for $\nu$ we then assume what is called that allowed approximation i.e. in the range where $H'$ is significant $\vec k\vec r\lt \lt 0$ and thus:
$$\psi_{e}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\tag{2}$$
To me these seem in conflict. Surly near in the region where  $\vec k\vec r\lt \lt 0$  our approximation of a plane wave solution fails and thus we should not be able to use (1) to get (2) as the wave function does not take this form. Please can someone explain to me why this we can make these approximations.

Answer (score 2):

The approximation condition is not $\vec k \cdot \vec r << 0$ but $\vec k \cdot \vec r << 1$.

Given a $Q_\beta \simeq 0.8$  Mev, in the worst case scenario this energy will be all converted in kinetic energy of the electron. So: 
$$
k = \frac{p}{\hbar} \simeq \frac{\sqrt{2 m_e Q_b}}{\hbar} \simeq 0.004 \mathrm{fm}^{-1}
$$

As the nuclear radius is of the order of the femtometer, the plane wave is almost constant in the nucleus and therefore the approximation works. The real problem is that the electrostatic attraction (or repulsion) is not negligible.